# MatDialog not displaying values that were updated via subscribe

Tags: angular, angular-material, subscribe

I have a MatDialog that isnt displaying the data being passed into it. Why is the last_name field populating correctly, but the companyDropdown not populating? The console output of the onSubscribe fires as expected- the view is just not updated after it fires.

HTML

```
    <h4>Last Name:</h4>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input placeholder="Last name:" [(ngModel)]="data.last_name">
    </mat-form-field>
<h4>Company: {{data|json}}</h4>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="data.company_id">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let s of data.companyDropdown" [value]="s.id">{{s}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS

```
export class UserEditDialogComponent implements OnInit{

constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UserEditDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ArgosUserModel,
    private svc: GreencardService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('dialog on init()')
    this.data.lgid = 1;//TEMP. need to pass from c#
    this.svc.getCompanies(this.data.lgid.toString()).
        subscribe(x => { this.data.companyDropdown = x; console.log('dialog with dropdown: ' + JSON.stringify(this.data.companyDropdown)) })
}
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that MAT_DIALOG_DATA data :  ArgosUserModel?  you try to attach other data to it.  Try to make an interface which adds ArgosUserModel and companydropdown data

Comment: Sorry, to clarify companyDropdown is a property of the ArgosUserModel, Im just initializing it in the OnInit (beforehand it is undefined)

Comment: please create a stackblitz demo for the question, it will be easy to correct there.

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me.   try first with a small static array/object. it should work.
also shouldnt your interpolation of s {{s}} not be something like {{ s.property }}?

```
 <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="data.optionselected">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of data.options" [value]="option.id">{{option.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```